# What are DDL and DML?

Tags: sql, ddl, dml

I have heard the terms DDL and DML in reference to databases, but I don't understand what they are.

What are they and how do they relate to SQL?

Answer (score 595, accepted):

[image: SQL command can be divided into three subgroups, DDL, DML and DCL]

The following is adapted from here [MySQL What is DDL, DML and DCL?](http://www.w3schools.in/mysql/ddl-dml-dcl/):

> **DDL**
>
> DDL is short name of Data Definition Language, which deals with
> database schemas and descriptions, of how the data should reside in
> the database.
>
> - CREATE – to create database and its objects like (table, index, views, store procedure, function and triggers).
> - ALTER – alters the structure of the existing database.
> - DROP – delete objects from the database.
> - TRUNCATE – remove all records from a table; also, all spaces allocated for the records are removed.
> - COMMENT – add comments to the data dictionary.
> - RENAME – rename an object.
>
> **DML**
>
> DML is short name of Data Manipulation Language which deals with data
> manipulation, and includes most common SQL statements such SELECT,
> INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE etc, and it is used to store, modify, retrieve,
> delete and update data in database.
>
> - SELECT – retrieve data from one or more tables.
> - INSERT – insert data into a table.
> - UPDATE – updates existing data within a table.
> - DELETE – delete all records from a table.
> - MERGE – UPSERT operation (insert or update)
> - CALL – call a PL/SQL or Java subprogram.
> - EXPLAIN PLAN – interpretation of the data access path.
> - LOCK TABLE – concurrency control.
>
> **DCL**
>
> DCL is short name of Data Control Language which includes commands
> such as GRANT, and mostly concerned with rights, permissions and other
> controls of the database system.
>
> - GRANT – allow users access privileges to database.
> - REVOKE – withdraw users access privileges given by using the GRANT command.
>
> **TCL**
>
> TCL is short name of Transaction Control Language which deals with
> transaction within a database.
>
> - COMMIT – commits a transaction.
> - ROLLBACK – rollback a transaction in case of any error occurs.
> - SAVEPOINT – a point inside a transaction that allows rollback state to what it was at the time of the savepoint.
> - SET TRANSACTION – specify characteristics for the transaction.

Comment: you might want to expand you answer a little in any future case that link would become unavailable

Comment: Sometimes you'll also see commands such as SELECT / SHOW / EXPLAIN / HELP split off from DML and grouped under `DQL`, with the Q from Query -- because they don't really manipulate anything.

Comment: TRUNCATE should be DML

Comment: Thanks friend, I'm starting and it's the best answer I found on the internet, God bless you.

Comment: @PeteAlvin, no it shouldn't:

`TRUNCATE` basically drops & re-CREATEs a table (resetting auto-incrementing IDs), and does not use transaction logs (unlike DML) => it won't work if other tables (even empty ones) reference that table at all.

Answer (score 352):

**DDL** is **[Data Definition Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language)** : it is used to define data **structures**.

For example, with SQL, it would be instructions such as `create table`, `alter table`, ...

**DML** is **[Data Manipulation Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language)** : it is used to manipulate **data itself**.

For example, with SQL, it would be instructions such as `insert`, `update`, `delete`, ...

Comment: DESCRIBE is DDL or DML?

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi I don't think `DESCRIBE` fits into any of the two. It just returns it's own representation of how a Table/DB is structured. You can achieve the same thing with e.g. `CREATE` but not as "human-readable"

Comment: If SELECT is considered DML, then DESCRIBE should be considered DDL.

Answer (score 45):

**DDL** is **Data Definition Language :** Specification notation for defining the
database schema.
It works on Schema level.

DDL commands are:

`create,drop,alter,rename`

For example:

```
create table account (
  account_number  char(10),
 balance integer);
```

**DML** is **Data Manipulation Language** .It is used for accessing and manipulating the data.

DML commands are:

```
select,insert,delete,update,call
```

For example :

```
update account set balance = 1000 where account_number = 01;
```

Comment: @isapir There are three general ways you can “manipulate” data in SQL:
 (1)You can change which results are presented.
 (2)You can change how the results are presented or organized (in terms of things like sort order, etc).
(3)You can change the underlying data.  In the first case, you can change which results are presented by using different WHERE clauses, JOIN predicates, etc, in a SELECT statement, ie- "select * from account ;" will give a much different result (assuming account has more than 1 row) than

select * from account where balance = 1000;

Comment: When you select the data in different formats, you modify the presentation of the data for that query, and not the data itself. The M in DML stands for Manipulation, or in laymen terms Modification, of the data. `SELECT` does not modify the data. Alternatively, `TRUNCATE` does, and is therefore a DML instruction and NOT a DDL one.

Answer (score 32):

[image]

#### DDL, **Data Definition Language**

- Create and modify the structure of database object in a database.
- These database object may have the Table, view, schema, indexes....etc

e.g.:

- `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`, `TRUNCATE`, `COMMIT`, etc.

#### DML, **Data Manipulation Language**

DML statement are affect on table. So that is the basic operations we perform in a table.

- Basic crud operation are perform in table.
- These crud operation are perform by the `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, etc.

Below Commands are used in DML:

- `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `SELECT`, `DELETE`, etc.

Answer (score 17):

In layman terms suppose you want to build a house, what do you do.

**`DDL`** i.e Data Definition Language

1. Build from scratch
2. Rennovate it
3. Destroy the older one and recreate it from scratch

that is

1. **`CREATE`**
2. **`ALTER`**
3. **`DROP & CREATE`**
4. `TRUNCATE`

**`DML`** i.e. Data Manipulation Language

People come/go inside/from your house

1. `SELECT`
2. `DELETE`
3. `UPDATE`

**`DCL`** i.e. Data Control Language

You want to control the people what part of the house they are allowed to access and kind of access.

1. `GRANT PERMISSION`

Comment: I wonder how we can build and use houses, without using such abbreviations? :P

Comment: TRUNCATE is DDL not DML.  That may not seem logical until you stop and look at how it's implemented and the permissions needed.  It's basically syntactic shorthand for a DROP followed by a CREATE using the same original schema.  You need DROP privileges to run it, and you cannot TRUNCATE if FOREIGN KEY constraints are defined, even if there are no entries pointing to it, meaning a DELETE without a WHERE clause would succeed.

Comment: @RichardSmith highly appreciate your comment, clarifying it anyone who reads this answer. And after I read this comment, it seems pretty logical that TRUNCATE is DDL

Answer (score 15):

> DML is abbreviation of **Data Manipulation Language**. It is used to retrieve, store, modify, delete, insert and update data in database.
>
> Examples: SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT statements
>
> ---
>
> DDL is abbreviation of **Data Definition Language**. It is used to create and modify the structure of database objects in database.
>
> Examples: CREATE, ALTER, DROP statements

Visit this site for more info: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/15/sql-server-what-is-dml-ddl-dcl-and-tcl-introduction-and-examples/

Answer (score 4):

[DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) = Data Definition Language, any commands that provides structure and other information about your data

[DML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) = Data Manipulation Language, there's only 3 of them, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.  4, if you will count `SELECT * INTO x_tbl from tbl` of MSSQL (ANSI SQL: `CREATE TABLE x_tbl AS SELECT * FROM tbl`)

Answer (score 3):

DDL is Data Definition Language: Just think you are defining the DB.
So we use CREATE,ALTER TRUNCATE commands.
DML is after defining we are Manipulating the data. So we use SELECT,INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE command.

Remember DDL commands are auto-committed. You don't need to use COMMIT statements.
DML (Data Manipulation Language) commands need to be commited/rolled back.

Answer (score 3):

## **DDL**

Create,Alter,Drop of (Databases,Tables,Keys,Index,Views,Functions,Stored Procedures)

### DML

Insert ,Delete,Update,Truncate of (Tables)

Answer (score 2):

In simple words.

DDL(Data definition language): will work on structure of data. define the data structures.

DML (data manipulation language): will work on data. manipulates the data itself

Answer (score 2):

**DDL** stands for Data Definition Language. DDL is used for defining structure of the table such as create a table or adding a column to table and even drop and truncate table.
**DML** stands for Data Manipulation Language. As the name suggest DML used for manipulating the data of table. There are some commands in DML such as insert and delete.

Answer (score 2):

**DD**L: Change the schema

**DML**: Change the data

Seems specific to MySQL limitations ([rails's source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L170-L187))

Answer (score 0):

A different response on DML may be helpful for those investigating [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/), a widely used open source tool for deployment of data transformations. ([See More detail here](https://blog.getdbt.com/what-exactly-is-dbt/).)

dbt facilitates "select" statements but not other DML commands.  See, e.g. ["Why can't I just write DML in my transformations?"](https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/why-not-write-dml/)