# How to view created row(s) in SQL+?

Tags: mysql

I created a dummy table and added some dummy values into the table. However, when I do - `DESCRIBE <table name here>;`, none of the values that I have entered are displayed.

For reference if needed, here's the code below:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP(
    EMPNO    NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    ENAME    VARCHAR2(10),
    JOB      VARCHAR2(9),
    MGR      NUMBER(4),
    HIREDATE DATE,
    SAL      NUMBER(7, 2),
    COMM     NUMBER(7, 2),
    DEPTNO   NUMBER(2)
);
```

<table created>

```
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7369, 'SMITH', 'CLERK',    7902, TO_DATE('17-DEC-1980', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 800, NULL, 20);
```

<1 row created>

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOQWK.jpg (what happens when I describe the table after entering the values)

Comment: run SELECT * FROM EMP;

Answer (score 0):

`DESCRIBE` is a [DDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578194/what-is-ddl-and-dml) utility statement used to view information about the column definitions in a table.

Use a DML statement like [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) to actually query the data:

```
SELECT * FROM EMP
```