# Pentaho Initialization Exception Error _0014 on starting Pentaho 6.1

Tags: oracle, pentaho

I'm trying to install Pentaho BA on CentOS 7 with Java 1.8
I downloaded the Community Edition 6.1.0.1-196. I run ./start-pentaho.sh and after correcting some bugs, everything worked.

Then I decided to Use Oracle as Repository and by following this guide : https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.4/0F0/0K0/040/0C0#title
I change some files.

When I changed Hibernate and Quartz everything were fine. Then I modified Jackrabbit ( repository.xml ) and context.xml and the error came up:

```
ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.DynamicallyPooledDatasourceSystemListener
```

org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.DynamicallyPooledDatasourceSystemListener

Now it's not even starting and the page looks like the image.

[image]

What did I put on the repository, or better what I changed is the password and the url.
I changed the url from *jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE* to **jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/servername** or **jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:servernam**e but none of them are working.

[image: Context.xml]

Before that, I create the repository and the 3 user as explained in the guide:

```
--THIS USER IS SPECIFIC TO THE DATABASE WHERE THIS SCRIPT IS TO BE RUN AND
--IT SHOULD BE A USER WITH DBA PRIVS.
--AND ALSO @pentaho should be replaced with the correct instance name
--
--NOTE: run create_repository_ora.sql before running this script, which
--      creates the pentaho_tablespace

-- conn admin/password@pentaho

drop user quartz cascade;

create tablespace pentaho_tablespace
  logging
  datafile 'ptho_ts.dbf' 
  size 32m 
  autoextend on 
  next 32m maxsize 2048m
  extent management local;

create user quartz identified by "password" default tablespace pentaho_tablespace quota unlimited on pentaho_tablespace temporary tablespace temp quota 5M on system;

grant create session, create procedure, create table to quartz;

--CREATE QUARTZ TABLES

CONN quartz/password

CREATE TABLE QRTZ5_JOB_DETAILS 
  (
    JOB_NAME  VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    JOB_GROUP VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(250) NULL,
    JOB_CLASS_NAME   VARCHAR2(250) NOT NULL, 
    IS_DURABLE VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
    IS_VOLATILE VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
    IS_STATEFUL VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
    REQUESTS_RECOVERY VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
    JOB_DATA BLOB NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ5_JOB_LISTENERS
  (
    JOB_NAME  VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL, 
    JOB_GROUP VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    JOB_LISTENER VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP,JOB_LISTENER),
    FOREIGN KEY (JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP) 
        REFERENCES QRTZ5_JOB_DETAILS(JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ5_TRIGGERS
  (
    TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    JOB_NAME  VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL, 
    JOB_GROUP VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    IS_VOLATILE VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(250) NULL,
    NEXT_FIRE_TIME number(13) NULL,
    PREV_FIRE_TIME number(13) NULL,
    PRIORITY NUMBER(13) NULL,
    TRIGGER_STATE varchar2(16) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_TYPE varchar2(8) NOT NULL,
    START_TIME number(13) NOT NULL,
    END_TIME number(13) NULL,
    CALENDAR_NAME VARCHAR2(200) NULL,
    MISFIRE_INSTR number(2) NULL,
    JOB_DATA BLOB NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP),
    FOREIGN KEY (JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP) 
        REFERENCES QRTZ5_JOB_DETAILS(JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ5_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS
  (
    TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    REPEAT_COUNT number(7) NOT NULL,
    REPEAT_INTERVAL number(12) NOT NULL,
    TIMES_TRIGGERED NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP),
    FOREIGN KEY (TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
        REFERENCES QRTZ5_TRIGGERS(TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ5_CRON_TRIGGERS
  (
    TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    CRON_EXPRESSION VARCHAR2(120) NOT NULL,
    TIME_ZONE_ID varchar2(80),
    PRIMARY KEY (TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP),
    FOREIGN KEY (TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
        REFERENCES QRTZ5_TRIGGERS(TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ5_BLOB_TRIGGERS
  (
    TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    BLOB_DATA BLOB NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP),
    FOREIGN KEY (TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP) 
        REFERENCES QRTZ5_TRIGGERS(TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ5_TRIGGER_LISTENERS
  (
    TRIGGER_NAME  VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL, 
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_LISTENER VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP,TRIGGER_LISTENER),
    FOREIGN KEY (TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
        REFERENCES QRTZ5_TRIGGERS(TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ5_CALENDARS
  (
    CALENDAR_NAME  VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL, 
    CALENDAR BLOB NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CALENDAR_NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ5_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS
  (
    TRIGGER_GROUP  VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (TRIGGER_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ5_FIRED_TRIGGERS
  (
    ENTRY_ID varchar2(95) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    IS_VOLATILE varchar2(1) NOT NULL,
    INSTANCE_NAME VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    FIRED_TIME number(13) NOT NULL,
    PRIORITY NUMBER(13) NOT NULL,
    STATE varchar2(16) NOT NULL,
    JOB_NAME VARCHAR2(200) NULL,
    JOB_GROUP VARCHAR2(200) NULL,
    IS_STATEFUL varchar2(1) NULL,
    REQUESTS_RECOVERY varchar2(1) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ENTRY_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ5_SCHEDULER_STATE
  (
    INSTANCE_NAME VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    LAST_CHECKIN_TIME number(13) NOT NULL,
    CHECKIN_INTERVAL number(13) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (INSTANCE_NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ5_LOCKS
  (
    LOCK_NAME  varchar2(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (LOCK_NAME)
);


INSERT INTO QRTZ5_LOCKS values('TRIGGER_ACCESS');
INSERT INTO QRTZ5_LOCKS values('JOB_ACCESS');
INSERT INTO QRTZ5_LOCKS values('CALENDAR_ACCESS');
INSERT INTO QRTZ5_LOCKS values('STATE_ACCESS');
INSERT INTO QRTZ5_LOCKS values('MISFIRE_ACCESS');
create index idx_QRTZ5_j_req_recovery on QRTZ5_job_details(REQUESTS_RECOVERY);
create index idx_QRTZ5_t_next_fire_time on QRTZ5_triggers(NEXT_FIRE_TIME);
create index idx_QRTZ5_t_state on QRTZ5_triggers(TRIGGER_STATE);
create index idx_QRTZ5_t_nft_st on QRTZ5_triggers(NEXT_FIRE_TIME,TRIGGER_STATE);
create index idx_QRTZ5_t_volatile on QRTZ5_triggers(IS_VOLATILE);
create index idx_QRTZ5_ft_trig_name on QRTZ5_fired_triggers(TRIGGER_NAME);
create index idx_QRTZ5_ft_trig_group on QRTZ5_fired_triggers(TRIGGER_GROUP);
create index idx_QRTZ5_ft_trig_nm_gp on QRTZ5_fired_triggers(TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP);
create index idx_QRTZ5_ft_trig_volatile on QRTZ5_fired_triggers(IS_VOLATILE);
create index idx_QRTZ5_ft_trig_inst_name on QRTZ5_fired_triggers(INSTANCE_NAME);
create index idx_QRTZ5_ft_job_name on QRTZ5_fired_triggers(JOB_NAME);
create index idx_QRTZ5_ft_job_group on QRTZ5_fired_triggers(JOB_GROUP);
create index idx_QRTZ5_ft_job_stateful on QRTZ5_fired_triggers(IS_STATEFUL);
create index idx_QRTZ5_ft_job_req_recovery on QRTZ5_fired_triggers(REQUESTS_RECOVERY);

commit;
```

Answer (score 3):

Still bumped into this problem with Pentaho 7.1.

After some digging it looks like the real error is logged in tomcat/logs/pentaho.log (truncated on every start) and **not** catalina.out.

```
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.ConfigurationException: Duplicate configuration element DataStore in Repository.
```

Solution is to make sure you only have 1 instance of DataStore class, 1 instance of PersistanceManger class etc in pentaho-solutions/system/jackrabbit/repository.xml.

Make sure to comment out all instances of following classes (which are there by default):

```
<DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore"/>
<FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
<PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.H2PersistenceManager">
```

Comment: This helped me... found my repository.xml was completely missing. Copied it from another tenant install and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit repository destination from default one to a new one make sure a user that is will be used to connect to a database is able to perform [DDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578194/what-is-ddl-and-dml) instruction like create table or view and so on.

When starting platform tries to create repository from scratch for the first time after a config changes. If it is not able to connect/create repository - it will just not start as you see on a screenshot. It just will not work without a repository.

All oracle connection string syntax is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html) as for Oracle jdbc driver - will be used under the hood. And of course you have to have jdbc driver jar in class-path.