# Pentaho CE server starts but cannot log in

Tags: pentaho

I'm trying to deploy a Pentaho CE Server following the official documentation; the server apparently starts correctly but then I cannot login, receiving a 404 while accessing `localhost:8080/pentaho`.

I tried the installation both on windows and on linux (under WSL2), with no avail. In the last attempt I tried, the downloaded code of Pentaho was under windows filesystem, the JCR repository in a docker container on WSL2 and I tried to start the server from WSL2.

First of all, I downloaded Pentaho (9.2.0.0-290) from the [download page](https://www.hitachivantara.com/en-us/products/pentaho-plus-platform/data-integration-analytics/pentaho-community-edition.html). Then I followed the official docs on how to set up and start the server, in particular I followed the steps to [set up and configure](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/8.3/Setup/Use_PostgreSQL_as_Your_Repository_Database_(Archive_installation)) the JCR repository on a local postgresql database (version 14).

I then activated the server with `start-server.sh` script, running it from inside WSL2. After waiting a while, Tomcat correctly started and in the logs I cannot see any specific error message saying something went wrong with the server startup (there are some warning messages here and there, but they appear to me to be related to secondary components). When accessing `localhost:8080/pentaho`, I see the following:
[image]

Here are the last lines of `catalina.out`:

```
19-Dec-2023 15:35:28.384 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/tomcat/webapps/pentaho] has finished in [614,132] ms
19-Dec-2023 15:35:28.386 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/tomcat/webapps/pentaho-style]
19-Dec-2023 15:35:43.383 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
19-Dec-2023 15:35:43.437 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/tomcat/webapps/pentaho-style] has finished in [15,051] ms
19-Dec-2023 15:35:43.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
19-Dec-2023 15:35:56.081 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
19-Dec-2023 15:35:56.116 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [12,677] ms
19-Dec-2023 15:35:56.119 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/tomcat/webapps/sw-style]
19-Dec-2023 15:36:08.751 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
19-Dec-2023 15:36:08.786 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/tomcat/webapps/sw-style] has finished in [12,668] ms
19-Dec-2023 15:36:08.794 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
19-Dec-2023 15:36:08.808 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [654785] milliseconds
```

`pentaho.log` report an error from yesterday when I have not correctly set yet the JCR repository, then there are no other error messages from today's attempts:
[image]

The following are the last lines of `localhost.2023-12-19.log` file:

```
    Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.ConfigurationException: Duplicate configuration element FileSystem in Repository.
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.ConfigurationParser.getElement(ConfigurationParser.java:334)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.ConfigurationParser.getElement(ConfigurationParser.java:308)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.ConfigurationParser.parseBeanConfig(ConfigurationParser.java:110)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfigurationParser.parseBeanConfig(RepositoryConfigurationParser.java:380)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfigurationParser.getFileSystemFactory(RepositoryConfigurationParser.java:1159)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfigurationParser.parseRepositoryConfig(RepositoryConfigurationParser.java:329)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfig.create(RepositoryConfig.java:354)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfig.create(RepositoryConfig.java:330)
        at org.springframework.extensions.jcr.jackrabbit.RepositoryFactoryBean.resolveConfigurationResource(RepositoryFactoryBean.java:91)
        at org.springframework.extensions.jcr.RepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBean.java:60)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784)
        ... 230 more
19-Dec-2023 15:35:28.068 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

The above exception is caused several lines before by a SEVERE logging:

```
19-Dec-2023 15:34:54.659 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [Spring Security Filter Chain Proxy]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChainProxy' defined in file [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'util:list#26000202' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'util:list#26000202': Cannot create inner bean 'sec:filter-chain#1bd3814a' of type [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain] while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sec:filter-chain#1bd3814a': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'basicProcessingFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'basicProcessingFilter' defined in file [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in file [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'util:list#2218c77a' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'util:list#2218c77a': Cannot create inner bean 'pen:bean#28de52db' of type [org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.objfac.spring.BeanBuilder] while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pen:bean#28de52db': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.objfac.spring.BeanBuilder#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daoAuthenticationProvider' defined in file [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security-jackrabbit.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'pen:bean#15d80a34' of type [org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.objfac.spring.BeanBuilder] while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pen:bean#15d80a34': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cachingUserDetailsService' defined in file [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/pentahoObjects.spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'UserDetailsService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'UserDetailsService' defined in file [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/pentahoObjects.spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'activeUserDetailsService' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activeUserDetailsService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in file [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security-jackrabbit.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userRoleDaoTxn' while setting bean property 'userRoleDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRoleDaoTxn' defined in file [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/repository.spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userRoleDao' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRoleDao' defined in file [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/repository.spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'adminJcrTemplate' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminJcrTemplate' defined in file [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/repository.spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jcrAdminSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jcrAdminSessionFactory' defined in file [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/repository.spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jcrRepository' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jcrRepository' defined in file [...../pentaho-server-ce-9.2.0.0-290/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/repository.spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.ConfigurationException: Duplicate configuration element FileSystem in Repository.
```

I'm pretty lost since I never used Pentaho before and I'm not used to all the components it is built with. Is there any way to check what's wrong? Is there any other method to deploy an instance of the server, for instance by using docker containers?

Answer (score 0):

I faced (somewhat) the same problem today. This is how I got it to work:

I did it on Debian Linux, manual version (not archive), with a manually downloaded Apache Tomcat 9.0.84 and using MySQL instead of PostgreSQL.

BTW you were following the docs for Data Integration and Analytics version 8.3 (based on your link); I used the 10.0 one.

At first, it didn't give me 404 but simply didn't load at all.

I checked the Apache Jackrabbit docs [here](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/jackrabbit-configuration.html) and read:

> The top-level structure of the repository configuration file is shown below. The <!DOCTYPE> declaration is optional, but if you include it Jackrabbit 1.5 will use XML validation to make sure that the configuration file is correctly formatted.

So I figured that if I removed/commented the <!DOCTYPE> declaration maybe it wouldn't enforce the expected structure and would stop complaining.

I did that, restarted the server, and after reloading the page, it gave the following error:

```
org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014
```

A quick google search yielded this SO post:
[Pentaho Initialization Exception Error _0014 on starting Pentaho 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375017/pentaho-initialization-exception-error-0014-on-starting-pentaho-6-1)

The solution provided there by user NrY

> Solution is to make sure you only have 1 instance of DataStore class, 1 instance of PersistanceManger class etc in pentaho-solutions/system/jackrabbit/repository.xml.

did the trick. The [Pentaho docs](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/10.0/Setup/Use_MySQL_as_your_repository_database_(Manual_installation)) for MySQL configuration say:

> Navigate to the pentaho/server/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/jackrabbit and open the repository.xml file with any text editor.

> In each of the sections, comment out any references that refer to other databases.

But of course the last ones, like

```
  <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
      <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository"/>
  </FileSystem>
```

don't really intuitively nor explicitly "refer" to a DB engine.

Anyway, once you update the `pentaho/server/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/jackrabbit/repository.xml` file with the additional directives commented out, save it and restart the server.

If it hangs and just shows `RepositoriesMeta - Reading repositories XML file: FromInputStream` in `catalina.out`, then wait a little bit, restart the service again, and now it should work properly.

Login is `Admin` and Password is `password`.

---

I know that this is what you asked

> Is there any way to check what's wrong?
> Is there any other method to deploy an instance of the server, for instance by using docker containers?

I feel I partially answered your first question and didn't answer the second one. However, the described procedure/explanation should hopefully both solve your problem (in your current, tried setup) and clarify a bit why it works :-).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give a try commenting out additional resources in the repository.xml, it was not so clear from the documentation what to configure and what to comment out.