# psycopg2: How to know when cur.rowcount does not mean number of rows?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm looking for a way to programatically determine the difference between `cur.rowcount` describing the number of rows available to fetch versus the number of rows affected.

For example:

```
>>> cur.execute('CREATE TABLE test (gid serial, val numeric);')
>>> cur.execute('INSERT INTO test (val) values (1), (2), (3);')
>>> cur.execute('SELECT * FROM test;'); cur.rowcount
3
>>> cur.execute('UPDATE test SET val = 1;'); cur.rowcount
3
>>> cur.fetchall()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch

>>> cur.execute('DELETE FROM test;'); cur.rowcount
3

>>> cur.execute('DROP TABLE test;')
>>> cur.rowcount
-1
```

Using Python 2.7 and psycopg2 2.6.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.description), `cur.description` will be `None` for operations without a result set.

Answer (score 4):

The distinction is simple at least in theory [`rowcount`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.rowcount) would be returned for all the **DQL** (Data Query Language) and **DML** (Data Manipulation Language) queries (your `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` etc). You'll have `-1` for **DDL** (Data Definition Language) queries - the (`CREATE`, `DROP`, `ALTER` etc).

In other words, you can expect `rowcount` to be defined (meaning >=0) if you actually manipulate data; if you work with the database/table schema - you'll have `rowcount = -1`.

As far as determining when the `fetchall()` would work or not, you can always go with the [EAFP approach](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) - try executing `fetchall()` and handle the `ProgrammingError`.

Also see:

- [What are DDL and DML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578194/what-is-ddl-and-dml)