# How can Delete be both a DDL and a DML statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ddl, dml

I am currently reading the offical Microsoft book 'Database Administration Fundamentals' in preparation to sitting it's exam.

I understand what DDL and DML are but Microsoft show DELETE as being both a DDL and DML statement. I have googled this but I cannot anything that confirms or denies this.

A good reference to this is the question: [What is DDL and DML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578194/what-is-ddl-and-dml) Which shows it as a DML. Below is the segments from the book:

> Data Manipulation Language (DML) is the language element that allows
>   you to use the core statements INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and MERGE to
>   manipulate data in any SQL Server tables. Core DML statements include
>   the following: • SELECT: Retrieves rows from the database and enables
>   the selection of one or many rows or columns from one or many tables
>   in SQL Server. • INSERT: Adds one or more new rows to a table or a
>   view in SQL Server. • UPDATE: Changes existing data in one or more
>   columns in a table or view. • DELETE: Removes rows from a table or
>   view. • MERGE: Performs insert, update, or delete operations on a
>   target table based on the results of a join with a source table.
>
> the six main DDL statements are as follows: • USE: Changes the
>   database context. • CREATE: Creates a SQL Server database object
>   (table, view, or stored procedure). • ALTER: Changes an existing
>   object. • DROP: Removes an object from the database. • TRUNCATE:
>   Removes rows from a table and frees the space used by those rows. •
>   DELETE: Remove rows from a table but does not free the space used by
>   those rows removed.

Is the book out of date/ wrong. Can someone help shed light on this I see conflicting lists of what are the full DDL and DML statements.

Comment: Another book reviewer found the same error: https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/RZD90UK9RSVLH/

Comment: Just to confirm, I did the exam (and passed) DELETE and TRUNCATE and most certainly DML. To remove the table structure DROP is used, DROP being DDL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you, `DELETE` is DML. Moreover, I dare say, `TRUNCATE` should also be considered DML, since logically is equivalent to a `DELETE` statement. The fact that `TRUNCATE` is a `DROP` and `CREATE` is not enough in my opinion to justify assigning it to DDL, since the two together, carried out as one atomic operation, do not affect the schema of the database.

Comment: Good luck with your exam then!

Comment: Note that, the SQL standard classifies TRUNCATE as a DML statement

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Are you sure you didn't mistype? Every resource I am looking at classifies TRUNCATE as a DDL statement.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It's listed in the chapter "Data manipulation" together with UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT statements. DDL statements are defined in the chapter "Schema definition and manipulation"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, it is a relief to know that I am not entirely alone in this... Thank you!