# When to use MODIFY and UPDATE database command in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

What i know is ->
Modify means it going to modify the record if it exists. If record is not there it going to add that record. Update means it is only modify the record.

Comment: And what is your exact question?

Comment: I've had to google this, just for refreshing my memory, but there is no command like `MODIFY` in MySQL that modifies column data

Comment: actually i want to know when to use modify over update in sql.

Comment: Modify does not exist in MySQL in the context which you are using the term. Neither does merge.you may be looking for insert...on duplicate key

Comment: [Modify](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) (Data Definition Language) changes structure of an object [update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) (Data Manipulation Language) changes data.  So if you're changing data UPDATE, or INSERT on Duplicate key update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to **Modify** *column data (as stated in your comment)*,
that would be an **UPDATE** command.

**MODIFY** in **RDBMS** is a **DDL** (*data definition language*) for defining *Entities* (tables) and their *properties* (columns).

I would encourage you to take a look at this question:

**[What is DDL vs DML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578194/what-is-ddl-and-dml/44796508#44796508)**