# Is JOIN operation ddl?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, ddl, dml

As join command joins 2 tables, is it like changing the schema for it to be considered a DDL?

Comment: No, joining is not DDL, it is DML.

Comment: *"join command"* There is no such thing in SQL as a `JOIN` command. `JOIN` is a **clause** used in `SELECT` statements, and as the [second duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44796508/5221149) says, `SELECT` statements are DML.

Comment: What do "like changing the schema" & "be considered a DDL" mean? We know what "changing the schema" & "DDL" mean.

Answer (score 5):

`JOIN` is *not* a "command". `JOIN` is an operator that operates on two tables (okay, table "equivalents" including views, table values functions, and subqueries). As an operator, it can appear in a `FROM` clause or (in MySQL) in `UPDATE` and `DELETE` clauses as well.

That's it, just an operator. It doesn't change the data structure.  It doesn't define the data structure. It is not DDL. It is an operator in the "data manipulation" language (DML) part of SQL. DML includes `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`.