# Delete Contents Of A table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

How Can I delete Contents of A table.. If I have 100 rows in a table and i want to delete all of them without droping a table how would I?

Comment: Two answers, but they are different. TRUNCATE is a DDL statement. It won't perform integrity checks or run triggers on delete.

Comment: @Benoit and it will also issue a `commit` statement that will end the current transaction

Comment: [What's the difference between TRUNCATE and DELETE in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/139630/851811)

Comment: @XaviLópez not in PostgreSQL (which the question is tagged).  Truncates are transactional in PostgreSQL. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html "TRUNCATE is transaction-safe with respect to the data in the tables: the truncation will be safely rolled back if the surrounding transaction does not commit."

Comment: @rfusca Thank you for providing this detail, unknown to me :)

Comment: @Benoit: PostgreSQL will do integrity checks and can fire TRUNCATE triggers. It's also transaction safe, you can even do a rollback.

Comment: Also, truncate in postgresql will reclaim all the disk space while delete will need vacuum to kick in to get it back.  ALSO since truncate IS DDL, if you're running slony replication, the truncate will not get replicated.  Pretty minor point unless you ARE in fact running slony, then it's a pretty major one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both given answers are correct.

The main difference between

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename
```

and

```
DELETE FROM tablename
```

is that `TRUNCATE` will reset the `auto_increment` value back to 1. It may make a difference if things have to be unique.

Comment: Question is tagged PostgreSQL as well. Postgres doesn't have that insane auto_increment issue. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html

Comment: And PostgreSQL doesn't reset any sequence, unless you ask for it using RESTART IDENTITY.

Answer (score 4):

Use [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) without a WHERE clause:

```
DELETE FROM tablename
```

This may fail if you have other tables that refer to it via foreign key references.

Comment: @Scorpion: in **PostgreSQL**, in the case of linked rows in other tables (via foreign key constraint) you can can cascade the DELETE like this `DELETE FROM tablename CASCADE`. But be very careful with that! You may or may not want to delete related rows.

Comment: Note that you can always delete in a transaction to see if you're losing rows you don't want to.  In pgsql everything except create/drop database/tablespace are transactable.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use TRUNCATE

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html (Thanks for PostgreSQL link to rfusca)

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Truncate also,it's faster than DELETE but TRUNCATE will not work under a table lock or transaction.

have a look at

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: Question is tagged PostgreSQL as well.  Truncates are transactional in postgres. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html