# What are differences between, and best purposes of, DROP, TRUNCATE, and DELETE? Can they be rolled back?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

**Delete is a DML(Data Manipulation Language). Delete command deletes records from the existing table.**The syntax for `Delete` is

```
sql> Delete from .
```

This Deletes All the Record From The TAble

```
sql> Delete from
      Where  **
```

This deletes a particular set of records.

Note:***Delete is not Autocommit Statement(In fact none of the DML are auto commit)***

Drop and Truncate both are DDL(Data Definition Language).

Drop {Delete or drops} the table with it's structure. It is autocommit statement. Drops Once fired can not be rolled back.

syntax:

```
sql>drop table
```

Truncate is the command used to delete all record from table. but the structure of the table remain same.It is also a autocommit statement.

syntax;

```
sql>truncate table**
```

Can we rollback the truncate?

Comment: This question, and its title, are a mess. Please clean them up.

Comment: Oracle provides extensive online documentation, complete with examples, of all their products.  I suggest that you consult the manuals appropriate for the version of Oracle you're using, read up on these commands, and try out the examples. In this way you will gain valuable experience using these commands, experience that you otherwise will be unable to acquire.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 12):

DELETE handles rows chosen with a `WHERE` statement. Its use is part of the discipline of running production applications.  For example, you might DELETE all rows that have been marked "complete" more than a month ago.

DELETE can be done as part of a transaction. That is, DELETE operations can be committed or rolled back.

TRUNCATE rapidly removes all rows from a table while maintaining the table definition. (Row by row DELETE can take time, especially for tables with lots of keys.) It comes in handy for such things as log tables that start out empty for each week's production. It has the convenient side effect of resetting the indexes and releasing unused disk storage. I have used TRUNCATE to wipe out the contents of a log table that used to contain millions of rows, to switch to an operational discipline where it only contains a weeks' worth of rows, for example.

DROP rapidly removes all rows and the table's definition. It's used most often in connection with setting up a DBMS schema for operations or migrating data to a new server.

TRUNCATE and DROP are considered data definition statements. As such they can't be part of transactions, and can't be rolled back.

If you find yourself using TRUNCATE or DROP in routine production, you should be careful to understand why you're doing so. They are blunt instruments compared to DELETE.

Comment: I heavily enjoyed your answer,as you have told each command's definition and practical place where I can think of them to use. But I would expect some more texts from you about the `DROP` commands practical application area.

Comment: @Babai:- Check out this:- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9004.htm This will surely fill the rest part which you are looking for!!!!

Comment: @RahulTripathi Can you help me to install Oracle11g in Ubuntu OS ? I used it in windows but no idea about how should I proceed in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Babai:- Although I would have loved to see this as a seperate question. But you can check this if that helps:- https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2461988?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

The `DELETE` command is used to remove rows from a table. A `WHERE` clause can be used to only remove some rows.

`TRUNCATE` removes all rows from a table. The operation cannot be rolled back and no triggers will be fired.

The `DROP` command removes a table from the database. All the tables' rows, indexes and privileges will also be removed. No DML triggers will be fired.

Check [this](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/difference_between_truncate_delete_and_drop_commands) out,

Answer (score 0):

"Drop" removes the table completely. It no longer exists.

"Truncate" is a fast way of removing all the rows from the table.

"Delete" removes rows that match a condition.

see also: [What's the difference between TRUNCATE and DELETE in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139630/whats-the-difference-between-truncate-and-delete-in-sql)