# Use of FLASHBACK in Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-administration, flashback

I have searched for the flashback command. Somewhere it is written we can rollback the truncate operation, and somewhere it is written we can't rollback. 
Can the FLASHBACK command in Oracle used to rollback the truncate table operation?

Comment: Flashback isn't the same as rollback, but no, it can't recover from a truncate and you can't do a flashback query past a truncate. It can recover from a `drop table` which might be the confusion. Perhaps you could quote and/or link to the sources for the two conflicting statements?

Answer (score 3):

You need to have **`Flashback Data Archive`** enabled.  Then the **truncate** could be reversed with a statement like this:

```
insert into <truncated_table> 
   select * from <truncated_table> as of timestamp <some time>;
```

Thanks to @[Jon Heller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409172/jon-heller) for adding this useful information about the new feature:

This requires version `11.2` or higher, which introduced support for [DDL statements such as truncate.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS640)

Comment: You still [can't recover from a truncate](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_flashback.htm#BJFJHDAG), though? Or rather, can't truncate if this is enabled; but either way you can't 'rollback' a truncate?

Comment: My intention was to focus on the other way round. I am not saying it would rollback the truncated data. But ***it will let the archived historical data to be accessed with standard SQL statements***

Comment: @Jon, thank you for the edit. Makes much more sense now.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise truncate (or the other DDL in JonHeller's link) is allowed from 11gR2. Interesting.

Comment: And just to add that this feature is not available Express Edition. http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/enterprise-edition/comparisons/index.html

Comment: @DavidAldridge Yes, saw your updated post here http://stackoverflow.com/a/139633/3989608