# Moving all rows from one table to another, deleting from original table but retaining auto_increment

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to correctly move **all** rows from one table to another and then delete them from the original table without resetting the auto_increment value.

The following seems to reset the auto_increment value... any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
$sql1   = "INSERT INTO archive SELECT * FROM main";
$result1 = mysqli_query($sqlsession, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error());

$sql2   = "truncate main";
$result2 = mysqli_query($sqlsession, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: truncate table xxx does that behavior, kinda nice actually. But not in your case

Comment: truncate deallocates data pages, is faster, then the value of auto_inc can be set with alter table. It's an option at least. Delete is logged. Slow. Got 20 rows, go with delete. 2 million, not a chance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM main
```

instead of truncate

Answer (score 1):

For speed, deallocation of data page size, I would steer toward truncate table always. Despite having to set the auto_inc back to what you want in your special case. So it's a one two punch like below.

```
truncate table myTable;
alter table myTable AUTO_INCREMENT = 200001;
```

[Truncate Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) manual page. Several stackoverflow posts have mentioned it. Here is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/139630).

If I had few rows, I would go with `delete from myTable`. With huge sets, never, and would use the above.

The existence of Foreign Key constraints factor into the likelihood of truncate or delete success. So consider that.

Comment: elaborated it so well ,   1+