# Safest way to empty table with mysql prompt

Tags: mysql

Hi I have Amazon rds which i can connect to using the mysql prompt

I want to empty a table using the prompt command line

What's the best way to do the above? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard `truncate` command to empty the required tables. If you want to truncate multiple tables follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912813/truncate-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-in-one-command) question.

Comment: Hi is delete better or truncate? Also what's the format of the command? An example would be appreciated

Comment: Command is `TRUNCATE TABLE your_table_name`. In terms of speed truncate is faster. Both delete and truncate has its own set of rules. Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139630/whats-the-difference-between-truncate-and-delete-in-sql) for a comprehensive comparison between both commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DELETE FROM `table_name`;
```

Notice the missing where clause, this will delete all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Data can't be deleted that's connected by a constraint.

> What you need is code that first removes constraints, then deletes the
>   data, and finally restores the constraints:

- See more at: http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/40967#sthash.NUmxsFr3.dpuf

Moreover, use `DELETE` command as you can `ROLLBCK` the operation. While using `truncate`, operation cannot be rolled back and no triggers will be fired