# Delete rows in MySQL database table based on column parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I have JSON data continuously inserted into a DB table but there are some rows which I need to delete concurrently based on the column value. For eg., I need to delete the rows which have a column value (time_min) of more than 90 minutes.

```
ID    time_min
1       50
2       30
3       91
4       40
5       93
6       95
7       40
```

Here I need to delete rows containing values more than 90 in time_min column.

This is the current code I'm using.

```
if($time_min >= 91){
        $sql = "truncate table_name";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Rows Dropped";
        }
    }
```

It clearly is deleting the entire table values which mess up in the loading of new values.
I would just want the rows that have column value of more than 90 in time_min (column name) to be deleted.

Would appreciate if someone can guide me on this.

Comment: `WHERE columnName > someValue`

Comment: It would probably help if you read a little of the MySQL manual

Comment: `truncate` will empty the entire table you need to use the `delete` function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139630/whats-the-difference-between-truncate-and-delete-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

You could use a where condition for check the 90 time_min for delete

```
  delete from my_table 
  where time_min  > 90
```

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
 DELETE FROM `table_name` where table_name.time_min>90
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [WHERE Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimization.html) condition on column in the query

```
DELETE FROM 'table_name' tbn WHERE tbn.time_min>90
```